# Problem plug in Go2StreetView

Tags: qgis, python

I have been using the Go2StreetView plugin since 2018.

I currently have Qgis 3.28.

I have a Google API key and my Maps JavaScript API and Street View Static API are active.

I contacted Google and everything is OK on their side.

I took a latitude/longitude that appears in the plug-in log and I tested it (it works with my key) :
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=43.136925158338535,6.042557572800607&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

below a capture of the log with another position
[image]

Comment: Have you logged an issue in the dedicated plugin issue tracker: https://github.com/enricofer/go2streetview/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was on this forum: here https://github.com/enricofer/go2streetview/commit/14a2d025c61f4d4f12ea5d4a320a8f8b0488df2b#diff-18ba38f812ed4e74126034ab1ae6d3ca9f125ec24d3573d8a152ae654068c7e3

Just search for the **resg2sv.html** file (in the plugin) and add the "**.53**".
The problem was related to a version number problem.
[image]

Comment: to administrators: I apologize, I just wanted to help people who were experiencing the same problem as me. I have no action in google (unfortunately). you will note that as of 2023/11/28, the term "trouble" is used in 3,438 questions and that of "plug in" in 1190 questions...

Comment: Link-only Answers are not permitted here. While you could link to the code in the Answer, you need a complete Answer that says what was wrong and how to fix it using the information in that link, or the Answer is likely to be converted to a comment.

Comment: @Vince Understood. THANKS